# plugin affecting all members of class instead of one element event is taking place on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a jQuery plugin to scale an object down on pinch down of that object.

I have multiple objects that need this interaction of the page so I gave them all a class and applied the plugin to the class.

However, when I pinch in on one, all of the members of the class are scaled.

How can I change the plugin so that only the one I am pinching in on is scaled?

Here is a live example of the page: http://goo.gl/OW5PKc

Here is the plugin:

```
function collapse(container, element){
    container = $(container).hammer({
        prevent_default: true,
        scale_treshold: 0
    });
    element = $(element);
    var displayWidth = container.width();
    var displayHeight = container.height();
    var MIN_ZOOM = 0;
    var MAX_ZOOM = 1;
    var scaleFactor = 1;
    var previousScaleFactor = 1;
    var startX = 0;
    var startY = 0;
    var translateX = 0;
    var translateY = 0;
    var previousTranslateX = 0;
    var previousTranslateY = 0;
    var time = 1;
    var tch1 = 0, 
        tch2 = 0, 
        tcX = 0, 
        tcY = 0,
        toX = 0,
        toY = 0,
        cssOrigin = "";
    container.bind("transformstart", function(event){
        e = event
        tch1 = [e.touches[0].x, e.touches[0].y],
        tch2 = [e.touches[1].x, e.touches[1].y]
        tcX = (tch1[0]+tch2[0])/2,
        tcY = (tch1[1]+tch2[1])/2
        toX = tcX
        toY = tcY
        var left = $(element).offset().left;
        var top = $(element).offset().top;
        cssOrigin = (-(left) + toX)/scaleFactor +"px "+ (-(top) + toY)/scaleFactor +"px";
    });
    container.bind("transform", function(event){
        scaleFactor = previousScaleFactor * event.scale;
        scaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_ZOOM, Math.min(scaleFactor, MAX_ZOOM));
        transform(event);
    });
    container.bind("transformend", function(event){
        previousScaleFactor = scaleFactor;
        if(scaleFactor > 0.42){
            $(element).css('-webkit-transform', 'scaleY(1.0)').css('transform', 'scaleY(1.0)');
        }
    });
    function transform(e){
        var cssScale = "scaleY("+ scaleFactor +")";
        element.css({
            webkitTransform: cssScale,
            webkitTransformOrigin: cssOrigin,
            transform: cssScale,
            transformOrigin: cssOrigin,
        });
        if(scaleFactor <= 0.42){
            $(element).animate({height:0}, function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }
    }
}
$.fn.collapse = function(filter) {
    return this.each(function(){
        collapse(this,filter);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the filter object that you are passing in is an jQuery object (an array of objects).  You have the this.each on the target (container) but not the filter which contains all the objects.  I would not pass in filter as a parameter.  Instead, use a selector (child or parent) at inside collapse()

Update:

```
$.fn.collapse = function() {

return this.each(function(){

    collapse(this);

});
```

}

if filter is a child of container the start of your function becomes:

```
function collapse(container){

container = $(container).hammer({

    prevent_default: true,

    scale_treshold: 0

});

element = $('.elementClass', container);
```

if you do not know which selector to use you can get more familiar with them here. 
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Can you explain how to do that? How to pass a selector?